# Pandas plot on 3 variables

Tags: python, pandas, plot, stacked-chart

Can someone help me define best way of visualizing 3 columns in pandas? I tried using stacked bar plot and searched for other solutions on SO, but nothing worked. Any help is appreciated. Here is a dummy pandas dataframe:

```
Name    hour    var
Nem      0      2
Kiz      4      1
Hue      5      2
Kiz      0      3
Nem      7      7
```

Comment: Can you tell more on why stacked bar plot doesn't work?

Comment: It works, but the figure is completely compressed because I have around 10000 rows in the dataframe. If it's possible I would like to have a bar plot with `Name` variable on x axis, color defined by `hour`, and height of the each colored part of bar defined by variable `var`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** is that what you want?

```
(df.pivot_table(index='Name', columns='hour', values='var',
                aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
   .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

[image]

Explanation:

```
In [55]: (df.pivot_table(index='Name', columns='hour', values='var',
   ....:                 aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
   ....: )
Out[55]:
hour  0  3  4  5  7
Name
Hue   0  6  0  2  0
Kiz   3  0  1  0  0
Nem   2  5  0  0  7
```

**OLD answer:**

you can use [seaborn](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) module for that:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.barplot(x='Name', y='var', hue='hour', data=df, saturation=0.8)
```

[image]

data:

```
In [20]: df
Out[20]:
  Name  hour  var
0  Nem     0    2
1  Nem     3    5
2  Kiz     4    1
3  Hue     5    2
4  Kiz     0    3
5  Nem     7    7
6  Hue     3    6
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I was wondering, is it possible to do this without `seaborn`, and could it be done as I intended with one bar per Name and different color? For example, just by looking at this figure I am not sure whether `hour 7` belongs to `Kiz` or `Nem`.

Comment: New answer should fit! Thank you very much!